# Using BIRT engine on AEM / CQ5

Tags: aem, birt, osgi-bundle

Was there anyone of you have successfully used BIRT engine in AEM/CQ5?

I am migrating an application which currently using BIRT engine to generate PDF file. I tried adding the BIRT engine dependency to my POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It compiles okay and can build the bundle jar file, but when I deploy to Apache  felix it cannot resolve the birth engine library.

```
Imported Packages   com.company.revamp.test,version=[1.0,2) from     com.company.revamp.test-bundle (371)
javax.servlet from cqse-httpservice (25)
javax.servlet.http from cqse-httpservice (25)
org.apache.sling.api,version=[2.1,3) from org.apache.sling.api (123)
org.apache.sling.api.request,version=[2.1,3) from org.apache.sling.api (123)
org.apache.sling.api.servlets,version=[2.1,3) from org.apache.sling.api (123)
org.apache.sling.jcr.api,version=[2.1,3) from org.apache.sling.jcr.api (74)
org.eclipse.birt.core.exception -- Cannot be resolved
org.eclipse.birt.core.framework -- Cannot be resolved
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api -- Cannot be resolved
org.slf4j,version=[1.5,2) from slf4j.api (6)
```

Any input is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to find osgi bundles for all the dependencies and install them on AEM.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/reapi.php mentions a number of library bundles that are required for the BIRT engine. It says "add the jars in the ReportEngine/lib directory to your classpath/buildpath".

Assuming those jars are proper OSGi bundles, the equivalent in an OSGi environment is to install and start these bundles in your AEM instance. In AEM that can be done by copying them to a content repository folder like `/apps/yourapp/install`.